# NuGet targets file package name variable

Tags: msbuild, nuget

I'm adding linked content via NuGet .targets file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\packages\MyPackage.1.2.3\tools\MyFiles\**">
      <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Is there a variable that I can use to refer to MyPackage.1.2.3 ?
I don't like the idea hardcoding package version here.

Comment: It should now be dead. The targets file is obsolete as NuGet uses another design in its latest releases.

Comment: @LexLi thanks, it would be nice if you provided reference link

Comment: It is rather strange your first idea is not to go to http://NuGet.org or Google.

Comment: @LexLi I did, however targets are still in official documentation. https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package#import-msbuild-targets-and-props-files-into-project So unless you can provide reference, your statements are not very helpful

Comment: https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore that's how ugly Microsoft documents big changes.

Comment: The targets file is still not obsolete as of April 2016 - it is a way to do flexible things such as injecting Copy commands, which no other technique allows.

Comment: Have you found a solution @SergejPopov? I currently have the same problem.